# Can't access values of list attribute reference of dynamically create Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, locker-service, dynamic

I am creating this Lightning component:

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:attribute name="record" type="Account" />
  <aura:attribute name="recordList" type="Account[]" />
   ...
</aura:component>
```

..dynamically using...

```
 $A.createComponent(
    "c:myComponent",
    {
        "record": cmp.getReference("v.account"),
        "recordList": cmp.getReference("v.accountList")
    },
);
```

I am perfectly able to access the single record but unable to access the record list.

```
myMethod: function(cmp) {
   cmp.get("v.record").Name = "Acme";  // Works

   for(var record of cmp.get("v.recordList")) {
      record.Name = "Acme";  // Fails
   }
}
```

Accessing the **recordList fails** with:

> Uncaught Action failed: myComponent$controller$myMethod [Cannot add
>   property Name, object is not extensible]

When I `console.log` both attributes `v.record` is a Map representing an SObject but the `recordList` is an obfuscated "thing"

```
Proxy {0: XI, 1: XI, 2: XI, 3: XI, 4: XI, 5: XI, 6: XI, 7: XI, 8: XI, 9: XI, length: 10}
[[Handler]]
:
Object
[[Target]]
:
Array(10)
0
:
XI {path: Array(3), Ja: "v.recordList.a0246000005mfQzAAI", Kd: false, Ga: a, pb: a, …}
```

Strangely we **could make it work** by temporarily assigning/casting it to another attribute of type `Account`.

```
for(var record of cmp.get("v.recordList")) {
    cmp.set("v.tempRecord", record);

    var temp = cmp.get("v.tempRecord");
    temp[field] = number;
    cmp.set("v.tempRecord", temp);

    cmp.clearReference("v.tempRecord");
}
```

*Why that? A bug? By design?*

Comment: Interesting question, have you tried treating the recordList like an array? e.g. iterate over it by doing cmp.get("v.recordList").forEach(function(record){record.Name = "Acme";}) for...of treats it as an iterable, rather than an array, and could possible be the source of the odd results.

Comment: Using forEach compared to for of didn't change a thing.

Comment: I think this is LockerService related based on the error but not sure why it's locked down. Try using Account[] as the recordList type instead of List. I've had better luck with arrays than lists in the Lightning framework.

Comment: According to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_proxy.htm LockerService seems to obfuscate any HTMLCollection type to an obfuscated Proxy. But why and how do I then access collections?

Comment: @RobertSösemann What release did you test this on? I tried to reproduce the issue on Winter 18 and the upcoming Spring 18, the assignment inside the for loop works fine. Will post my repro steps as an answer because there is limited space here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [incredibly helpful developer of the Aura Platform team](https://twitter.com/GrayJustise) did a Hangout session with me to debug this and confirmed that this is either an open bug or something that will be fixed in Spring'18.

For the time being this way to access the reference works as a workaround

```
myMethod: function(cmp) {
   ...

   for(var i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
        var record = cmp.get("v.records."+i);
        record['Name'] = "Acme";
        cmp.set("v.records." + i, record);
    }
}
```

So the important thing is not the loop type or Aura type of the attribute. It's the way how I get the reference by `cmp.get("v.records." + i)` out of the array and how I set it using `cmp.set("v.records." + i, record)`.

*Note: My code was way more complex than the samples I gave here. Instead of and Account array it was a Map. Instead of accessing the Name field it had to work for generic fields and other similar nifty complexities*

Comment: great spot, seems like `cmp.get()` is doing the magic casting refrerences into real records.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine on Winter 18 and Spring 18(upcoming) releases. Here's the code I used to repro the issue.

**Apex Controller**

```
public with sharing class AccountController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> findAll() {
    return [SELECT id, name
            FROM Account
            LIMIT 50];
    }
}
```

App code

```
<aura:application controller="AccountController">
    <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="account" type="Account" />
     App
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <c:containerCmp account="{!v.account}" accountList="{!v.accounts}"/>
</aura:application>
```

App Controller

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event) {
        var action = component.get("c.findAll");
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            component.set("v.accounts", a.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.account", a.getReturnValue()[0]);
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**c:containerCmp**

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:attribute name="account" type="Account" />
  <aura:attribute name="accountList" type="Account[]" />
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    container cmp
    {!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

c:containerCmp controller

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp) {
        $A.createComponent(
            "c:myComponent",
            {
                "record": cmp.getReference("v.account"),
                "recordList": cmp.getReference("v.accountList")
            },
            function(newInnerCmp, status, errorMessage) {
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    var body = cmp.get("v.body");
                    body.push(newInnerCmp);
                    cmp.set("v.body", body);
                }
            }
        );
    }
})
```

**c:myComponent**

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:attribute name="record" type="Account" />
  <aura:attribute name="recordList" type="Account[]" />
  <ui:button press="{!c.clickHandler}" label="Show account details"/>
  <br/>
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.recordList}" var="recordd">
      {!recordd.Id} : {!recordd.Name} <br/>
  </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

c:myComponent controller

```
({
    clickHandler : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        cmp.get("v.record").Name = "Acme";  // Works
        for(var record of cmp.get("v.recordList")) {
            record.Name = "Acme";  // Suppose to fail here, but works fine
        }
        // Optional step to reflect the mutation in the UI
        // cmp.set("v.recordList", cmp.get("v.recordList"));
    }
})
```

Comment: @RobertSösemann Let me know what you did differently compared to the repro posted above.

Comment: The only obvious difference is that instead of passing an Account[] we pass a Map<Id, CustomObject__c> and populate recordList by initializing it as [] and pushing items from recodsMap[recordId]

Comment: Ravi, please see my "workaround" answer below. I got help by Kris from the Aura team and there seems to be a bug. He is going to file it and said there is a slight chance there is already a fix delivered in Spring'18. In case you discuss and assess this issue again internally I would love to see an aditional answer or comments by you.